# F5 para ver form php

Tags: php, html, php7

Cree un `form` donde edito información, de manera local me funciona de manera correcta, cuando lo cargo al `hosting`, no funciona, cuando abro el `form`, se ve la ultima información visualizada, si doy `F5` si me carga bien los datos de la `BD`.
¿Qué puede ser?

Código de carga a la `BD`

```
$sqlg="SELECT * FROM tb_liqui where id=$id ";
$resultg=mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlg);
if ($resultg == false) {
die('Error SQL: ' . mysql_error());
}
$mostrarg=mysqli_fetch_array($resultg);
```

Código de carga de los campos

```
                        <div class="form-group" data-for="obsrv2">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-10"  for="obsrv2">Observaciones consulta:</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="obsrv2" rows="5" data-form-field="obsrv2"> <?php echo $mostrarg['obsrv2']; ?></textarea>
                    </div>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a lo que te estás refiriendo la verdad, ¿en qué momento llamas la información?  ¿dónde la editas? ¿y dónde te das cuenta que no actualiza?

Comment: Cuando se abre el form, deberia llamar la informacion de la BD, cuando se abre la primer vez, muestra informacion, pero no la real de la BD, cuando refresco la pagina ahi si muestra la informacion real.

Comment: El form se despliega o se abre en otra pagina?

Comment: Se abre en otra pagina

Comment: Y la consulta la haces en el mismo archivo en donde está el html?

Comment: Si, de forma local en mi Portatil funciona sin inconveniente, solo cuando lo subo al hosting pasa eso, de echo acabe de crear un nuevo campo en el formulario, y para ver ese campo toca actualizar.

Comment: Como le estas pasando la consulta de php al html?

Comment: Los datos de conexión son los correctos en el hosting?